# Searching Channel with Youtube API

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I am using `Youtube Data Api V3` in my `iOS` App. Can some body give me some example for search thing the some Channel by name.

I am trying in the following way but its not working

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/list?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&part=snippet&type=channel&q=AnimalPlanetTV

Can anybody help me how i can get the channel data by name

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is a [live example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet&forUsername=AnimalPlanetTV&_h=1&)

You need to use [Channel list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?hl=FR) of API V3

The result is like that with `snippet`

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"gMjDJfS6nsym0T-NKCXALC_u_rM/RKAMAh1QnoE3ilYYcvWIqvcDEZo\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"gMjDJfS6nsym0T-NKCXALC_u_rM/MenmiFqQVVN5JQ9MJpC9gddZ4Lw\"",
   "id": "UCkEBDbzLyH-LbB2FgMoSMaQ",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Animal Planet",
    "description": "Animal Planet is the world's only entertainment brand that immerses viewers in the full range of life in the animal kingdom with rich, deep content via multiple platforms and offers animal lovers and pet owners access to a centralized online, television and mobile community for immersive, engaging, high-quality entertainment, information and enrichment.",
    "publishedAt": "2007-02-14T18:26:59.000Z",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-FEsYkupUb-A/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/6SiqnVvRZJY/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-FEsYkupUb-A/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/6SiqnVvRZJY/s240-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-FEsYkupUb-A/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/6SiqnVvRZJY/s240-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: that gives you the exact searched name, but what if user wants to search for 'car' and there it suppose to show many othesrs results?

Comment: then you have multiple result

Answer (score 0):

For Searching AnyYoutube Channel

https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&q=yoursearchquery&key=yourkey